# What does <copy> mean?

Tags: key-bindings

When I run `M-x clipboard-kill-ring-save`, emacs tells me:

> ```
> You can run the command `clipboard-kill-ring-save' with <copy>
> ```

How do I use `<copy>`? `M-x <copy>` simply says `[No match]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It refers to the "Copy" key found on e.g. Sun keyboards, as in this photo (second key from the left, third from the bottom):

[image: Photo of left part of Sun keyboard]

Answer (score 2):

Emacs refers to special ("pseudo") keys with `<angle brackets>`.  From the [EmacsWiki on key notation](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsKeyNotation):

> Some keys are referred to as “function” keys or “pseudo” keys. This includes keys that are not among the keyboard function keys `F1`,…`F12`. It includes keys that might not be on your keyboard, but are on other keyboards. **It even includes keys, such as `<insert-file>`, that are not on any keyboard, anywhere.** For one thing, **Emacs treats menu bindings as key bindings**: a menu item is implemented as a pseudo key.

So, for example, `<left>` refers to the left arrow key.  I've never heard of the `<copy>` key, so I presume it's referring to the menu binding rather than a key.

Comment: Ah! The menu binding. That makes sense.